# How to undo a Format of a PC or just restore specific files?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, reinstall

I did **Reinstall** Windows a while ago, but I forgot to backup some specific files (Some iPod Touch Applications, which is what I REALLY need), And I don't know how to restore them, I tried the programs: 
**Data Recovery**, **Recover My Files** and **TuneUp Utillities 2011** and none of them worked, any way to restore them?

Comment: Important: Don't touch the drive. If you can avoid having the PC powered, do so. Any, **any**, writing to the drive will likely overwrite and permanently destroy some of the files you're trying to recover. ALso, try Piriform Recuva.

Comment: I already touched it, i used it to write this question, already Re-Installed iTunes, and other programs

Comment: Oh. I hope you had backups, otherwise you're going to need a lot of luck on your side, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah i must have a lot of luck

Answer (score 3):

Doubtful, when you installed Windows it overwrote some of the data, the longer you use windows the more data it will overwrite, overwritten data is Unrecoverable by any means.

What old data is left might be able to be recovered by [Get Data Back](http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm)

You should not install this software on the hard drive you are trying to recover, attach the hard drive to another PC and run the recovery software from there. I doubt you will recover much of your old data.

Comment: It is critical that you stop using the computer you reinstalled windows on in order to maximize the chance you'll be able to recover the information. Get Data Back is one of the better, more easy to use, tools out there. PC Inspector also has some free tools that work OK.

Comment: +1 for GetDataBack - I just pulled a ton of data off a drive that a customer of ours accidentally reinstalled Windows on TODAY actually.

Comment: Yup, I only use that software, have for many years, its a no bs "git er done" file recovery software. The sooner you recover the better.

Comment: Get Data Back says `**Use only on Just formatted hardrive**` (or something like that)

Comment: It can be used on any windows formatted hard drive, ignore that message.

Answer (score 1):

There are to important factors:

1. Did you do a "quick format" or a real format?

   If it was a real format you have no chance of recovering those files yourself. Only with some luck a professional data recovery lab might be able to help.
2. How long has it been since you formatted the drive?

   The more you use your computer (install programs, updates, etc.) the smaller your chance of recovering files gets.

A good (but expensive) software is Ontracks Easy Recovery.

Comment: it was "Restore Factory Settings" - which rebooted into the HP Restore thingy, i think maube 20th march.